# colormap not returning the expected color for value

Tags: python, matplotlib, colormap

I'm experiencing some problems with matplotlib colormap.
I've set up this example code to reproduce my problem.

```
%matplotlib inline

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches
from matplotlib import style
from matplotlib import colors
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

style.use('ggplot')

plot_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'from': [[0, 0], [10, 10], [15, 15], [20, 20]],
    'to':[[10, 10], [20, 20], [30, 30], [40, 40]],
    'value':[0, 5, 10, 15]
})
plot_df['connectionstyle'] = 'arc3, rad=.55'
plot_df['arrowstyle'] = 'Simple, tail_width=1, head_width=10, head_length=15'
plot_df
fig, ax = plt.subplots()


vmin = 0
vmax = 15
scalarmappable = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(norm=colors.Normalize(vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax), cmap='YlOrRd')
cmap = scalarmappable.get_cmap()
cbar = fig.colorbar(scalarmappable, ax=ax)

ticks = np.linspace(vmin, vmax, 5)
cbar.ax.set_yticks(ticks)
cbar.ax.set_yticklabels([f'{tick:.0f}' for tick in ticks])  # vertically oriented colorbar
cbar.outline.set_linewidth(0)



for _, row in list(plot_df.iterrows()):
    start_x = row['from'][0]
    start_y = row['from'][1]
    dest_x = row['to'][0]
    dest_y = row['to'][1]
    plt.scatter([start_x, dest_x], [start_y, dest_y], color='k')
    p = patches.FancyArrowPatch(
        (start_x, start_y),
        (dest_x, dest_y),
        connectionstyle=row.connectionstyle,
        arrowstyle=row.arrowstyle,
        color=cmap(row.value)
    )
    ax.add_patch(p)
   
fig.tight_layout()
```

[image]

As you can see in the image all arrows are yellow and color is function of cmap, so I'd expect at least the two arrows to be orange and red.

Does someone has a fix for this?

Comment: You need a variable `my_norm=colors.Normalize(vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax)` and then use that norm both in ` plt.cm.ScalarMappable(norm=my_norm, ...)` and in `patches.FancyArrowPatch(....,  color=cmap(my_norm(row.value)))`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works correctly, but `cmap` scales from 0 to 255, while `row.value` iterates from 0 to 15 in your loop. The difference between 0 and 15 is very small, so that's why it appears not to be working. (Though you can just see that the last arrow is slightly more orange than the first arrow).
Think about how to scale, for example, scaling by factor 15 would be a simple (hacky) fix: `color=cmap(row.value * 15)`

[image]

**Edit:**
Note that setting `vmax=255` would correctly display the scale bar.

Comment: @Guimoute When the input is integer, a `cmap` treats the input as going from 0 to 255. When the input is float, it is treated as going from 0 to 1.

Comment: your remark *"setting `vmax=255` would correctly display the scale bar"* is probably **not** what is wanted here. The idea of a colorbar is to show the relation between the colors and their corresponding "real world" value, not the value that matplotlib is using internally.